# Перенаправления звука с аудиовыхода в аудиовход

Tags: python, pyttsx3

У меня есть программа которая из текста делает звук при помощи разных голосов и проигрывает его, так вот мне надо чтобы эти звуки были слышны моим собеседникам или в игре, то есть чтобы с аудио  выхода оно уходило на аудио вход.
Вот код который преобразует текст в аудио:

```
import pyttsx3
from threading import *

tts = pyttsx3.init()
voices = tts.getProperty('voices')
wee = []

def poisc():
    for voice in voices:
        wee.append(f"{voice.name}")

def pusk1(golos, tx):
    tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru')
    for voice in voices:
        if voice.name == golos:
            tts.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
    tts.say(tx)
    tts.runAndWait()
    tts.save_to_file(tx, "lol.mp3")
    print("im save")
```

Ещё забыл добавить, надо чтобы это делалось с помощью библиотеки python но не с помощью сторонних программ.